# What structure type do I use for HTML content (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, html, sql

I want to put a minified string of HTML into a database row - bare in mind it could be pretty large string, what kind of structure type do I use out of the following:

http://d.pr/2URu

I've tried `LONGTEXT` but that doesn't seem to work when I try to insert.

Comment: What does `that doesn't seem to work when I try to insert` mean? Surely, you are getting an error of some sort, why aren't you mentioning everything you encounter while trying out a piece of code? It's not like we can replicate your issue and come up with an answer. Wild guess: you are not escaping quotes properly and you're getting an SQL error that you're not printing out.

Comment: I think you're right, i'm not escaping quotes!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`LONGTEXT` is probably excessive -- it allows data sizes up to 4GB.

`MEDIUMTEXT` allows 16MB.

`TEXT` allows 64KB.

`TINYTEXT` allows only 255 characters.

Very few HTML documents are going to be 64KB in size, so a `TEXT` ought to be suitable for you. If you really want to be safe, go for a `MEDIUMTEXT`.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: What if the `HTML` content will be storing `img` tag with `base64`? The safest would be `LONGTEXT`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use TEXT. What are the options you were thinking about?

Comment: Just storing the HTML output using `htmlentities` of course, ill give that a go now.

Answer (score 1):

**Text**. Which one of them depends on the size of the HTML content you're planing to store

Answer (score -4):

I think that tinytext is ok if you page is not too long ! ?

Comment: @Merianos - it wasn't me that downvoted you, but tinytext only allows 255 characters. That really doesn't sound like enough to safely store an HTML document.

Comment: @Brogrammer thanks a lot, but just I like to know what's wrong with my answer and downvoted from the member who downvoted me. Again thanks a lot :)

Comment: `TINYTEXT` isn't ok. For reason why it isn't ok, check MySQL docs and see how much data `TINYTEXT` can store. Downvoted because answer isn't proper or exact. "I think" without giving reasons why isn't the way you answer exact questions, it's pure maths.

Comment: OK you are right, I see now, that was a speed falt. I knew that I had to choose TEXT but I was not 100% sure for that. In any case the question answered

Comment: -1, tinytext is not OK for HTML. In fact it's one of the worst types for any kind of storage.