# What's the best way to store html code in mysql?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What structure type do I use for HTML content (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833465/what-structure-type-do-i-use-for-html-content-mysql)

What's the best way to store HTML code in MySQL?

If I have, let's say an entire page of source code, and I want to save it, what data type should I use for the column in MySQL?

Also, is it better to just save the code as a file, with a filename equal to the primary key, a unique id, created in MySQL (maybe to save space in the data file?)

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?  Are you trying to build a dynamic page?  Personally I don't believe you should ever store html in a database.  If you are building a dynamic pages that have common pages you might be better to make the multiple generic files that you can pass the data and parameters to.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would recommend TEXT. I think blobs are more for multimedia etc. than text.

[wikipedia blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object)

Answer (score 10):

Data type to store HTML in Database would be `TEXT`

But, you have to encode it using `mysqli_real_escape_string`
$dbh is the database connection handle you used to connect to your MySQL instance using `mysqli_connect()`

```
$html="Yor HTML";
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (html) 
VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$html) . "')"
```

or use **Prepared Statements**

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string - deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **[BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)** or **[TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)**