# Store Long Html Code for Articles in MySQL

Tags: php, android, html, mysql

I would like to display articles (via html code) in my `android app` with `HtmlView`(WebView). In fact, it might be very long and with `<!"` tags etc.

The best I thought to encode&decode it as base64 and use.

I know this might be duplicate but answers didn't satisfy. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What structure type do I use for HTML content (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833465/what-structure-type-do-i-use-for-html-content-mysql)

Comment: I had posted an answer but, I really don't think I got which is your concern.

Comment: @Juan
I saw that, thanks. Do you recommend me to store in which type, text?
And does html syntax affect my database?

Comment: I think your answer was good as well.  There really is no reason to encode it.  Just store it and pull to use as necessary.  What type you store it as depends on how large the pages you want to store are.  Take a look at the link I marked as duplicate for to see an explanation of that.

Comment: how long is long LONGTEXT will store 4 gig

Comment: Count of words in article is approximately 2000 words. plus html syntax

Comment: I just searched, mediumtext is okey for me. It will be max 2-3MB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Html is already text, yo won't benefit of encoding it in base64.
In any case it would make it longer because you need 4 characters to represent 3.